# Passing Data from ListViewAdapter to Array

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I want to pass data from EditText List to a String Array. I have created three classes as the followings : 
ListViewStudentNames.
ListViewStudentNamesAdapter.
MainClass.
The classes as the followings :

ListViewStudentNames.

```
public class ListViewParentsNumber {
private  String StudentName ;
private String StudentID ;
private String ParentNumber ;

public String getStudentName() {
    return StudentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    StudentName = studentName;
}

public String getStudentID() {
    return StudentID;
}

public void setStudentID(String studentID) {
    StudentID = studentID;
}

public String getParentNumber() {
    return ParentNumber;
}

public void setParentNumber(String parentNumber) {
    ParentNumber = parentNumber;
}

public ListViewParentsNumber(String StudentName, String StudentID, String ParentNumber)
{
    this.ParentNumber = ParentNumber ;
    this.StudentID = StudentID ;
    this.StudentName = StudentName ;
}


}
```

ListViewStudentNamesAdapter

```
 public class ListViewParentsNumberAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewParentsNumber> {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ListViewParentsNumber> mData;

public ListViewParentsNumberAdapter (Context mContext, ArrayList<ListViewParentsNumber> mData) {
    super(mContext, R.layout.parents_shape, mData);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = new ArrayList<ListViewParentsNumber>();
    this.mData.addAll(mData);
}
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.parents_shape, null);
    }
    TextView Name  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Student_name);
    Name.setText(mData.get(position).getStudentName());

    EditText Parent_Number  = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Parent_Number);
    Parent_Number.setText(mData.get(position).getParentNumber());

    return convertView;
}


}
```

my Main Class
is

```
public class CHECKING_PARENTS_NUMBERS extends ActionBarActivity {
private String USERNAME ;
private String GRADE_ID  ;
private String CLASS_ID ;
private Button Save ;
private String USERID ;
private Button Back ;
private String PARENTS_PHONE_NUMBERS[];
private String STUDENT_ID_ARRAY[] ;

private ListView mListView;
private ListViewParentsNumberAdapter listViewStudentNameAdapter;
private ArrayList<ListViewParentsNumber> listViewStudentNames;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checking__parents__numbers);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Student_names_List);

    Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveEditing) ;
    Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Back);
    new GET_PARENTS_NUMBER(USERNAME,GRADE_ID,CLASS_ID).execute();
    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();

        }
    });

    Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ListViewParentsNumber country;
            for (int i = 0; i < listViewStudentNames.size(); i++) {
                country = listViewStudentNames.get(i);
                PARENTS_PHONE_NUMBERS[i] = country.getParentNumber() ;
            }\\This Loop doesn't store the PARENTS_NUMBER IN the EditText in the array
            new Update_Absence(USERNAME, GRADE_ID, CLASS_ID,PARENTS_PHONE_NUMBERS).execute();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please frame your question properly as it is unclear what your problem is.

Comment: Passing the Values in the EditText to an Array

Comment: From EditText to array or vice-vers ?

Comment: And where is the EditText and which array you are talking about ?

Comment: In the Class ListViewStudentNamesAdapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107074/discussion-between-ama989-and-shadab-ansari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `TextWatcher` to your EditText and in `afterTextChanged()` update the values in your List.

```
Parent_Number.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                 listViewStudentNames .add(position, Parent_Number.getText().toString().trim());
            }
        });
```